# AWS S3 - specific file restriction policy problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to set policy like in below:

I want to restrict some of extension. Basically, I want to upload only .jpg, .png, and .gif extension.

I got this policy from : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-allow-certain-file-types/

I got the following error when I try to apply this policy.
`Resource must not be empty`

How can solve it?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1464968545158",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/exampleuser"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*.jpg",
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*.png",
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*.gif"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "NotResource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*.jpg",
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*.png",
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*.gif"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It appears that you are wanting to allow a specific user to upload objects of those extensions to the bucket. **Question:** Does this user have any existing permissions that allow them to upload to the bucket? ALSO, does the bucket currently have a Bucket Policy (if so, what does it do)? The reason I ask is that generally if you want to give permission to a specific user, it is better to add the permission on the IAM User rather than on the bucket. Also, if the user does not already have any permission to access the bucket, then the `Deny` is not required. Please let us know more.

Comment: No, what I want is for no user to upload any files other than certain files (eg .jpeg, .png). @John Rotenstein

Comment: In that case, your Bucket Policy should do the job. I tried in on my own bucket (replacing the bucket name and IAM ARN) and it saved without any error. Did you remember to replace `DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET` with the name of the bucket? Also, please note that the first part of your policy is granting a specific user the permission to upload jpg/png/gif files to the bucket, while the second part is preventing _every_ user (including you!) from uploading any files that are _not_ jpg/png/gif.

Comment: I understood about first part. How can I change second part for preventing every user? Can you give me an example, please @John Rotenstein

Comment: Could you please clarify your actual requirements? Are you simply wanting to grant a specific user permission to upload any jpg/png/gif file? If so, the first part of your policy be sufficient, because that is what it is granting. There is no need to `Deny` anything unless it has already been `Allowed` because access is Denied by default. I would also recommend putting that policy on the IAM User rather than on the Bucket, since it just relates to one user (but either method will work).

Comment: I explain. I want only .jpg, .png, .gif, .svg, .doc, .docx files to be loaded in buckets. I don't want to allow any user to upload any other files other than these. @John Rotenstein

Comment: Then your policy is correct. It both allows that user to upload those files, and prevents everybody (including you) from uploading any other files. You say "I don't want to allow any user to upload any other files other than these", and that is exactly what it will do.

Comment: That's right but my policy gives me an error like ``Resource must not be empty``. Also, I edited bucket names.  @John Rotenstein

Comment: I tried your policy on my own bucket (replacing the bucket name and IAM ARN) and it saved without any error. If it is still giving you an error, try with just the `Allow` section, or just the `Deny` section to narrow-down what might be causing that error. That is, only have one statement, rather than the two statements.